# Replace a particular string in script with another string if a pattern is found common between two scripts

Tags: c++, mysql, shell

iam having two sample script:

SAmple1:

```
Header1234578
12345abcdN qwerty
67890efghN qwerty
Trailer0000002
```

Sample2:

```
12345
65432
56789
```

So,what i need is, if a string from sample2 matches with a string in sample1,
field at position 10(i.e N )should be replaced with Y only in that line where match is found.

Attempted code:

> cat Sample2 | while read LINE
>       do
>       $FLAG_FOUND=grep $LINE Sample1
>       if[[$? -eq 0]]
>       {
>       sed 's/^(.{9})./\Y/' Sample1 >>Sample3
>       }

Comment: I have to write a shell script in unix for this

Comment: ok but you must show your attempted code in question

Answer (score 0):

You can use this awk command:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]; next} FNR>1 {
   for (i in a) if ($1 ~ i) {
     $0 = substr($0, 1, 9) "Y" substr($0, 11)
     break
   }
} 1' sample2 sample1

Header1234578
12345abcdY qwerty
67890efghN qwerty
Trailer0000002
```